# save and load keras.callbacks.History

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, generator

I'm training a deep neural net using Keras and looking for a way to save and later load the history object which is of `keras.callbacks.History` type. Here's the setup:

```
history_model_1 = model_1.fit_generator(train_generator,
                          steps_per_epoch=100,
                          epochs=20,
                          validation_data=validation_generator,
                          validation_steps=50)
```

`history_model_1` is the variable I want to be saved and loaded during another Python session.

Comment: Why do you want to save and reload it? It can't be saved but there might be options if what you need is for example the value of the loss and metrics at each epoch...

Comment: Training the model takes more or less 12h on my laptop. I want to save data needed for plotting loss function and accuracy values

Comment: Thanks :-) I tried to answer with that in mind

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`history_model_1` is a callback object. It contains all sorts of data and isn't serializable.

However, it contains a dictionnary with all the values that you actually want to save (cf your comment) :

```
import json
# Get the dictionary containing each metric and the loss for each epoch
history_dict = history_model_1.history
# Save it under the form of a json file
json.dump(history_dict, open(your_history_path, 'w'))
```

You can now access the value of the loss at the 50th epoch like this :

```
print(history_dict['loss'][49])
```

Reload it with

```
history_dict = json.load(open(your_history_path, 'r'))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Could you add the lines of code to reload the history?

Comment: it says `TypeError: Object of type 'float32' is not JSON serializable` for me

Comment: Unfortunately this would only work after the method `fit` is ended (and `history_model_1` is created), but it would be helpful to save such an object with a callback itself, in a schedule. Also, how would I restore the history if the training has been interrupted, so it could be checked, continued and updated with a new round of training session?

Answer (score 11):

You can create a class so you will have the same structure and you can access in both cases with the same code.

```
import pickle
class History_trained_model(object):
    def __init__(self, history, epoch, params):
        self.history = history
        self.epoch = epoch
        self.params = params

with open(savemodel_path+'/history', 'wb') as file:
    model_history= History_trained_model(history.history, history.epoch, history.params)
    pickle.dump(model_history, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

then to access it:

```
with open(savemodel_path+'/history', 'rb') as file:
    history=pickle.load(file)

print(history.history)
```

Comment: I got `TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object`. Maybe history is not serializable and therefore it fails?

Comment: The greatest way!

Answer (score 10):

You can use Pandas to save the history object as a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(history_model_1.history).to_csv('history.csv',index=False)
```

The JSON approach results in a `TypeError: Object of type 'float32' is not JSON serializable`. The reason for this is that the corresponding values in the history dictionary are NumPy arrays.

Comment: This results with `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Comment: How to load history after that?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from Tobias, use this updated version

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(history_model_1.history.history).to_csv('history.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename='log.csv'
history_logger=tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(filename, separator=",", append=True)
history_model_1 = model_1.fit_generator(train_generator,
                          steps_per_epoch=100,
                          epochs=20,
                          callbacks=[history_logger],
                          validation_data=validation_generator,
                          validation_steps=50)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).