# how can I interrupt training during learning and have the weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a cnn and I forgot to put early stopping or save the model in my code and I put a large epoch for training, but after about 250 epochs it did not have any improvements. is it possible to interrupt learning but have the learning weights until this time? because it takes about one day for this learning:( I used keras and python 3.6
THank you.

Comment: Unfortunately the learning weights will be lost :(

Comment: :( and when I save the model and load it again, is it possible to plot the loss for train and test? I mean, now after training I have the history and can plot but when I save the model and load it, is it possible to plot the loss function on test or validation or not?

Comment: Are you running it from the command like, or possibly in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969006/save-and-load-keras-callbacks-history

Comment: I'm using spyder

Comment: Isn't there a "pause" button? Many IDEs (I don't know spider) will keep the kernel up when you pause the code. Then you just get the var name you want.

Comment: no, I could not find anything:(

Comment: The stop button of spyder resides in the upper-right corner of its IPython console.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for your loss... you can't do anything, from now on follow this..
booyah!

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("model_weights.h5", 
                             monitor='val_Accuracy', 
                             verbose=1, 
                             save_best_only=True, 
                             save_weights_only=True, 
                             mode='auto', 
                             #save_freq=1
                             )

early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_Accuracy', 
                      min_delta=0, 
                      patience=30, 
                      verbose=1, 
                      mode='auto')
#optimizer Tuning
tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
                            learning_rate=0.001,
                            beta_1=0.97,
                            beta_2=0.97,
                            epsilon=1e-07,
                            amsgrad=False,
                            name="Adam",
                      )

resnet_model.compile(
                            optimizer='Adam',
                            loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                            metrics=['Accuracy']
                    )

R50_model= resnet_model.fit(
                            train_dataset,
                            #steps_per_epoch=30,
                            epochs=10, 
                            validation_data= validation_dataset,      
                            #callbacks=[checkpoint,early],#if you need to early stop it 
                            callbacks=[checkpoint] 
                            verbose=1
                            )
```

**It does really work for me !**

Follow this Article to resume your trainings and do even more : https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-resume-an-interrupted-training-session-in-fastai-77c4f36cd3a1

Answer (score 0):

you can save checkpoints to then proceed from these when training was disrupted. More info can be found at this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).