# Get TF callbacks back on track when kernel is disconnected

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Sometimes my training routines with TensorFlow take too long and the kernel (aka Google Colab) will disconnect. The models weights, I can get them back with a regular ModelCheckpoint callback, but other callbacks like EarlyStopping and ReduceLROnPlateau will reset. (Actually, ModelCheckpoint does also reset, which is an issue if I set `save_best_only = True`).

I've been wondering if there is a way to save the history the callbacks are tracking for situations like these.

I did try to save my full model as it includes the callbacks, figured that would suffice, but since my model is not an instance of Sequential, I have to save the weights only.

Comment: another way to solve this issue is to prevent Colab from getting disconnected. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-to-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting

Comment: @AmitGupta that used to work if the kernel was idle but my main issue is the maximum limit timeout. (Also, now Colab shows a captcha eventually if there is no user interaction.)

Comment: take a look at this one then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969006/save-and-load-keras-callbacks-history

Comment: That is surely more in the direction I need, only it does not allow auto saving the callback history, neither restoring it after a training crash. Thank you though.